# Understanding the release naming convention for bash. Which release came first, 4.3.30 or 4.3-11?

Tags: bash, security, debian, versioning, debian-jessie

Bash vulnerability [CVE-2014-6271](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-6271) is reported as fixed in version 4.3-11 on Debian Jessie.  On a Debian Jessie server, I executed the command `bash --version` and it said the version is 4.3.30. Is this server vulnerable to the CVE-2014-6271? Which release came first, 4.3.30 or 4.3-11?  How do I tell?

Specifically, I don't understand the release naming convention and the significance of `"-"` vs `"."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4.3.30` is a version of bash.

`4.3-11` is the version of the bash Debian package in Jessie that was created based on bash `4.3`.

So bash `4.3.30` is newer than bash in Debian package `4.3-11`.

Part of the version after the dash (`-`) is called `debian_revision`

From [the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#version):

> The version number of a package. The format is:
>   `[epoch:]upstream_version[-debian_revision]`.
>
> **upstream_version**
>
> This is the main part of the version number. It is
>   usually the version number of the original (“upstream”) package from
>   which the .deb file has been made, if this is applicable. Usually this
>   will be in the same format as that specified by the upstream
>   author(s); however, it may need to be reformatted to fit into the
>   package management system’s format and comparison scheme.
>
> **debian_revision**
>
> This part of the version number specifies the version
>   of the Debian package based on the upstream version. It may contain
>   only alphanumerics and the characters + . ~ (plus, full stop, tilde)
>   and is compared in the same way as the upstream_version is.
>   It is optional;
>
> The package management system will break the version number apart at
>   the last hyphen in the string (if there is one) to determine the
>   upstream_version and debian_revision. The absence of a debian_revision
>   is equivalent to a debian_revision of 0.